# Has 'Orange is the New Black' changed in season 3?

Tags: orange-is-the-new-black

I'm currently on a binge-watch in OISTNB season 3 and I must say: it seems very different from season 1 and 2. The focus is way less on Piper, everything seems to be peaceful, there are hardly any groundbreaking decisions to be made and in my opinion it has changed from being a drama-comedy to a sitcom.

I know we shouldn't discuss anything here about whether my opinion is correct or not; my question simply is: did anything change on the show from season 1-2 to season 3? Like another director, writer etc. that could explain why I perceive it so differently? Perhaps the book by Piper Kerman also took that direction?

Comment: I'm not a fan of the show, but a quick glance at the season 3 lineup suggests that they've got quite a few actors demanding bigger parts, they've renewed for 3 further seaons which means that they can have story-arcs that stretch over 1-2 years, they're looking to make the show into a franchise (I can smell the spinoff already), etc. http://www.indiewire.com/article/why-netflix-renewed-orange-is-the-new-black-for-three-seasons-20160205

Comment: I think you're actually asking if the production team changes at all?